# Android Studio does not install latest application on device

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following some tutorials about building apps in Android Studio, but for some reason it's not launching/installing the latest version of my app when I click 'run'.  I have to manually uninstall the app on the phone and then click run after making changes in Android Studio for the app to get updated.  Any ideas?

Here is the console output:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: htc-htc_one_m8
Uploading file
    local path: /home/brandon/AndroidStudioProjects/JustJava/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.justjava
No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am force-stop com.example.android.justjava
Launching application: com.example.android.justjava/com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.example.android.justjava/com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.android.justjava/.MainActivity }

Waiting for process: com.example.android.justjava
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8638', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8638', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: What does the console show during the apk deployment process?

Comment: @stkent Added console output.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Try uninstall older version or changing version number for testing. I think it's bug.

Comment: Yep! So it looks like no change in the apk is detected (`No apk changes detected`), so the app is just quit and reopened. What are you changing in between consecutive builds - code, build config, resources?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that line too.  I'm changing code (xml and Java): creating methods, changing how the display looks, etc.  Stuff that should account for a difference in the apk.  


@oguzhand It seems like a bug...sometimes the app will pick up changes but then sometimes it won't.  Interesting/annoying hah :P

Comment: Bug is still there (AndroidStudio 1.5)

Comment: I did not have this bug in 1.5, but I do have it in 2.2.1 !   What a mess...

Comment: for me reconnection of the adb works

Comment: Try @OğuzhanDöngül in comments may be helpful

Comment: nothing works. android studio is getting suciker by the day

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.

Android Studio thinks that there are no changes and doesn't install the new APK. A workaround is to disable the "Skip installation if APK has not changed" option in Run > Edit Configurations.

[image: Screenshot on Android Studio 1.4]

---

I'm using Android Studio 1.4
Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160901

Comment: Thanks. Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: what a heck of a bug.. i wasted enough of the time before i disabled silly option..(silly as it doesnt work as intended..)

Comment: Didn't work. Skip installation is not ticked and it still doesn't install latest version.

Comment: I had to do that and also to invalidate caches in in Android Studio (File > Invalidate Caches / Restart)

Answer (score 36):

Android Studio thinks that there are no changes and doesn't install the new APK. A workaround is to disable the "Skip installation if APK has not changed" option in Run > Edit Configurations >Android Application > app >Miscellaneous .
Then uncheck "Skip installation if APK has not changed".

Another problem like this is instant Run you can manage it by :- Just go to "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployement -> Instant Run" and just disable it. With this Android Studio builds from scratch each time but it's better than not building it right.

Comment: Instant & Run is no more present on Android Studio 3.5.2

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a bug 
you can find more info [Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211802)

Disabling instant run option in edit configuration and adding -r flag to the install flags is best work around for now.!

Comment: What does -r flag mean?

Comment: -R: Repeat the activity launch <COUNT> times. Prior to each repeat, the top activity will be finished. you can find other switches developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html

Answer (score 4):

option in Run > Edit Configurations >Android Application > app >Miscellaneous . Then uncheck "Skip installation if APK has not changed".
THEN -->  option in Build > clean project and rebuild project
and reinstall APK in your device.

THIS WORKS FINE FOR ME, HOPE THIS HELP OTHER ALSO

Comment: Worked for me. I don't know what raised the problem at the first place.

Comment: Clean project for me has been good. I've just lost 4 hours while thinking my code was wrong. Not really happy with AS.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason why the app might fail to install/start is if you've set up a "work profile".

The app might still be installed in your "work" profile and thus won't be re-installed nor uninstalled when starting through Android Studio. The "main"-profile portion of the app is "disabled" though and thus the activity can't be started.

Solution: manually uninstall the work-app, then redeploy from Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I get this I just kill the app on the device, then run it. Throw in a log statement to clarify you're on the right build, just something that you know you changed for this build.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of above solution but didn't work for me. 
I solved by Opening a new project or some other existing project (being in current project) in a new window and then I closed the previous one..
I opened again the previous one and clicked on run and it worked for me like a charm..:)

Answer (score 0):

**Run on a Phone**

Set up your device as follows:

Connect your device to your development machine with a USB cable. If you're developing on Windows, you might need to install the appropriate USB driver for your device. For help installing drivers, see the OEM USB Drivers document.
Enable USB debugging on your device by going to Settings > Developer options.
Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Run the app from Android Studio as follows:

In Android Studio, click the app module in the Project window and then select Run > Run (or click Run  in the toolbar).
In the Select Deployment Target window, select your device, and click OK.

[Please refer the link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice)