# Android Studio No apk changes detected

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio showing below message,

```
Target device: asus-asus_
Uploading file
    local path: D:\xxxxxx\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.xxxxx
No apk changes detected.
Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.
```

I am using Asus Zenfone 2. How to solve the problem. Every time i have need to uninstall the app then reinstall after that i am getting the new changes.

Comment: Did you tried to make a clean an build on android studio or invalidate cache?

Comment: yes, tried, but it worked for one time after that it same thing happen, no change detected.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Android Studio? Or disconnecting and then reconnecting the device?

Comment: Then this was an issue on the android studio, although I thought this was fixed, aparently is not, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76539. 
This happen to me many times before, although I just needed to kill the adb and restarted it again, try that maybe can help you. On windows adb process get stuck sometimes and you need to kill through task manager

Comment: Thank's @iGoDa but i am using the android studio 1.4, i checked the link before.

Comment: @Shubham i tried 2 pcs, One of my office & other one of my home, same thing happening after one time

Comment: Can you show us the contents of build.gradle file?

Comment: [Here the build.gradle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4ukshfv7lck49r/build.gradle?dl=0)

Comment: while this is still not fixed.. a easier way is to follow the accepted answer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684530/android-studio-does-not-install-latest-application-on-device