# Firestore Error "Could not deserialize object"

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int (found in field 'ww') (ww is priority)

I know about Firestore Rules and I think I had no mistakes,
I have confirmed already that my RecyclerView works with orderBy("priority") well.

I was putting a random data set in the Firestore Console
And I got a problem. (every data-set have exactly same format, only values are different)

I have declared priority as an int and I have not made it "number" but "string",
so I know I was wrong so I fixed it but after all this happened even I fixed this,
the problem wasn`t gone (I changed to it to as "number" again)

It appears the same error again and again.

only when I delete this whole collection, no more error occurs.(and after put it same data as number then nothing problem)

why is this happening? (if it had a problem only once, then after all results are failed continuously(above error))

I don`t know why but it seems just one mistakes pollute whole collection.

I guess I found a new bug in Firestore. Does anyone know about this?

thank you

---

it's weird. if it didn't occur any errors even once, then It can be edited
I made a `String` data and change it to "number" and launched my app and nothing happened. (it works fine)

but I once got error then even I updated it correctly, the error occurs again forever

```
public class Note {
    private int ww;

    public Note() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Note(int ww) {
        this.ww = ww;
    }

    public int getWw() {
        return ww;
    }
}
```

And

```
Query query =  databaseRef.orderBy("ww", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
            .setQuery(query, Note.class)
            .build();

    mAdapter = new NoteAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

my database structure URL

[image]

Error Message

> Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int (found in field 'ww')

--

I think this is android studio's problem with firebase networking that is something I don't know. I realized that because when I launch the app only inside Emulator (not Android Studio Run Button) it works fine. but still don't get it. Why is this happening?

and I tried this [Android Studio does not install latest application on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684530/android-studio-does-not-install-latest-application-on-device)

but not working

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I put the code

Answer (score 1):

actually,
this answer worked for me

[Android Studio does not install latest application on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684530/android-studio-does-not-install-latest-application-on-device) by Rahul

adding -r flag to the install flags was a solution and this also make a little problem
like I don`t know why but I have to run or launch the app twice not only once.
(if you know about this please answer this)
then it`s fixed. but thanks for not being permanent!

Answer (score -1):

change

private int w;

in Note class to public.