# App not installed in my phone; All method I found didn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

Upgraded Android Studio and the APK doesn't work, it says "App not installed"
I send the APK through Google Drive.

1. The phone has not installed my app before.
2. Restarted for using Google Drive install
3. Tried `multiDexEnabled true`
4. Tried `android:testOnly="false"`
5. Tried Generated signed APK with v1, v2, and both
6. Tried Generated signed APK for debug and release with #5
7. Tried "Build -> Build Bundle / APK -> Build APK
8. Tried to increase the version Code
9. Tried Invalidate Caches / Restart
10. Tried to disable Play Protect from Play Store

They all didn't work at all
My phone still shows "App not installs" even I press "Install anyway"

Don't know if this related: "App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent-filler."

EDIT: Manifast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tang.helloworld" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <application
        android:testOnly="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".setup.SetUpActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:name=".menu.MenuActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".selection.Activity_List_Level" />
        <activity android:name=".selection.Activity_List_Industry" />
        <activity android:name=".selection.Activity_List_Function" />
        <activity android:name=".selection.Activity_List_Filter_Function" />
        <activity android:name=".book.Activity_Book" />
        <activity android:name=".selection.Activity_List_Record" />
        <activity android:name=".feedback.Activity_Feedback" />
        <activity android:name=".game.Activity_Game" />
        <activity android:name=".game.Activity_Game_Finished" />
        <activity android:name=".game.Activity_Level_Up" />
        <activity android:name=".book.Activity_All_Book"></activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: check the sdk version of app and the phone

Comment: @TaNG_N get the device details

Comment: phone: Android 8.1.0, API 27
app: compileSdkVersion 28; minSdkVersion 25

Comment: Is the dynamic feature added to your AndroidManifest? Share your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: hey bro, can you show me your manifest file?

Comment: updated for manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple reasons that I have faced previously

- Can you please check whether the instant run mode is activated or not? for
  me sometimes this instant run created problem.
- Another option is maybe your phone doesn't support the specified SDK version.
- There is a chance that the phone doesn't enable the permission to install the app 
  from unauthenticated sources.

Comment: 1. Instant run mode isn't activated
2. I got another phone and installed successfully before updating Android Studio
and the phone got the same error now (both phone)
3. Not sure about this one, any solution for this?

Comment: if you want to make a debug build by using ADB and direct install on your device is that ok? 
you can make an attempt by creating a emulator then you will get the idea whether it is android studio problem or your device

Comment: direct install is alright so i guess its apk problem?

Comment: yes..then definitely there is some settings in your android studio configuration that causes the problem.

Comment: Okay then, which config should i check for?

Comment: this link has a good solution which might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684530/android-studio-does-not-install-latest-application-on-device

Comment: @TANG_N update the Gradle version to the latest and build.